# React native deploy new native app only when native code has changed, and deploy through codepush and apphub for changes in javascript

Tags: ios, react-native, hockeyapp, app-hub, code-push

I have a react native application I want to deploy to hockeyapp, app store, and play when the native code has changed, and I want to deploy through CodePush or AppHub when only JS has changed.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the project in two repositories, one containing the native app, and one that contains the js.

The one that contains the native app can reference the js repository using a git submodule.

Then set up a separate CI pipeline for them so that the native project runs the whole build and deployment pipeline to the app store etc, and the js repository only deploys through CodePush/AppHub.

Comment: Another common solution that we've seen is folks using branches to differentiate between the stores they release to automatically (e.g. deploy to HockeyApp when commits are made to the "beta" branch). Here is a great post by ZeeMee that explains their workflow:  https://zeemee.engineering/zeemee-engineering-and-the-quest-for-the-holy-mobile-dev-grail-1310be4953d1#.hcq1vrfzt